# Launching an application from the Contact list

Tags: android, android-contacts, launching-application

Im looking for a way to make a link between contact and Android Application. An example of this is Whatsapp, this application binds to a contact and makes it possible to launch the whatsapp application with the number as parameter. I have not been able to find a way of accomplishing this, and was wondering if there was someone with expierence in this area.

Your help is very much appreciated

Comment: While I agree with the answer pointing you to the `<intent-filter>`, I am very skeptical that the `<intent-filter>` the answer provides is a good one to use. If you already have Whatsapp installed, install [the App Browser app](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.japanesecrackers.appbrowser), and you can examine the Whatsapp manifest to see what they might have in there that would tie them to a contacts app.

Comment: I think `intent-filter` is definitely the right way to achieve this. I am quite sure it is - at least part of - WhatsApps solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I didn't try this, but I hope my answer will be helpful for you.

To clarify, you want your app was in the 'Connections' section as Whatsapp app:
[image]

In this case, you should use [Account Manager](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/accounts/AccountManager.html)
If you go to the phone Settings in the "Accounts and Sync" you should see all of the custom accounts registered on your phone:
[image]

Sorry, for not providing exact code snippets, but I hope this was useful for you, and you can Google your question (looking for Account Manager).
Maybe these links will be useful for you too:

[create custom account android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11404504/create-custom-account-android) 
[Custom Account Type with Android AccountManager](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13275847/custom-account-type-with-android-accountmanager)

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking for, with this information I found the following link that adds code to your answer:
http://www.c99.org/2010/01/23/writing-an-android-sync-provider-part-2/

Answer (score 1):

[Intent-Filter](http://www.androidside.com/docs/guide/topics/manifest/intent-filter-element.html) is the way to go!

In your AndroidManifest.xml you have to tell Android that your app can respond to such an Intent.
Example:

```
 <application ... >
    <activity ... >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.SENDTO" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />
            <data android:scheme="sms" />
            <data android:scheme="smsto" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
</application>
```

Than your Activity can access the Intents data when called.
Example:

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    // get intent-data
    Intent intent = getIntent();
    if (Intent.ACTION_SENDTO.equals(intent.getAction())) {
        Toast.makeText(this, intent.getDataString(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
    // close activity
    finish();
}
```

With this code you can choose your App as the receiver whenever another App (e.g. Contacts) fires such an Intent.
Example to fire such an Intent (Screenshot from Contacts):
[image: Screenshot from Contacts]

Comment: Thank you for your answer, I am sure the use of intent filters is the way to go, but the filter that I have to use is for me unclear. In your example you are adding a listener to the SendText button, but I do not want to override the users capability of using the textbutton. I would like an extra button like an app as whatsapp is using